# What kind of resource it is in Community

Tags: community, static-resources

I'm maintaining a community and found the following link in the source code:
https://xxx.cs19.force.com/[CommunityName]/resource/1/.../xxx.js

Note the number 1 after /resource/ in the url, usually resource id is much longer.
It doesn't look like regular resource. What it could be?

I tried to find that js file but no luck.
Where can it be?

Comment: If it is a static resource, it has the name after the Id, Like following - `force.com/resource/1477737553000/StaticResourceName/..../xxx.js`. What template you are using for communities?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce) the number after the ***/resource/*** in url is a timestamp (*LastModifiedDate* of static resource).

In my case the url was hardcoded thats why I got elder version of a file. Once I changed it to the valid number I got the recent file in static resource.